# Reading a local file in angular 1.5?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get data from a user, in the form of a txt file. In my HTML, I created the following:

```
<input type="file" name="file" accept=".txt" id="file"/>
```

This allows a user to select a valid txt file from their disk. My question is, how can I work with this data? How would I download the data from the local file and use it in my application?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend this: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Comment: if u don't need to support legacy browers, [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) may be the best choice.